# How to extract a nested type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have an import of an interface called `IFoo`

```
interface IFoo {
  name: string;
  version: number;
  init: (arg1: string, arg2: number) => Promise<string[]>;
}
```

All I care about is the type of `init` is there a way to extract it such that I can this interface elsewhere? ie.

```
inteface ICustom {
  properties: {
    group: string,
    init: IFoo.init
  }
  amount: number
}
```

Comment: `init: typeof IFoo.init`

Comment: `typeof IFoo.init` is only legal if a value named `IFoo` exists, but it doesn't

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can used an indexed access type:

```
interface IFoo {
  name: string;
  version: number;
  init: (arg1: string, arg2: number) => Promise<string[]>;
}

interface ICustom {
  properties: {
    group: string,
    init: IFoo["init"]
  }
  amount: number
}
```

Comment: Just curios to get it "straight from the horses mouth". What is the correct terminology "indexed access type", "type query" or "index type query"? I am pretty sure I have seen all of them used, but which is the official one ?